# Argument Error with AWS Access Key and ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I am trying to add Secret Keys to my app by using the Carrierwave gem however when I run it I keep getting the below error message

Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)

Here is my config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:              'AWS',
    aws_access_key_id:     Rails.application.credentials.aws_key,
    aws_secret_access_key: Rails.application.credentials.aws_secret,

  }
  config.fog_directory  = Rails.application.credentials.aws_bucket
end
```

Here is my log:

```
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
        93: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
        92: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        91: from /Users/homefolder/Sites/tuts/source/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
        90: from /Users/homefolder/Sites/tuts/source/bin/spring:15:in `require'
        89: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        88: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        87: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        86: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        85: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        84: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        83: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        82: from /Users/homefolder/Sites/tuts/source/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        81: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        80: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        79: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        78: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        77: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        76: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        75: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        74: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        73: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        72: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        71: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
        70: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        69: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        68: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        67: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
        66: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
        65: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
        64: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51:in `start'
        63: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89:in `log_to_stdout'
        62: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
        61: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
        60: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
        59: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        58: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        57: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        56: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        55: from config.ru:in `<main>'
        54: from config.ru:in `new'
        53: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        52: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        51: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        50: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in `require_relative'
        49: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        48: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        47: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        46: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        45: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        44: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        43: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        42: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        41: from /Users/homefolder/Sites/tuts/source/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        40: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
        39: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
        38: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        37: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        36: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        35: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        34: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        33: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        32: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        31: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
        30: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
        29: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
        28: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        27: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        26: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        25: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        24: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        23: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
        22: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
        21: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
        20: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        19: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `each'
        18: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:614:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        17: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in `load_config_initializer'
        16: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
        15: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:657:in `block in load_config_initializer'
        14: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
        13: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        12: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
        11: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
        10: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
         9: from /Users/homefolder/Sites/tuts/source/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
         8: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/carrierwave-1.3.1/lib/carrierwave.rb:14:in `configure'
         7: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/carrierwave-1.3.1/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:161:in `configure'
         6: from /Users/homefolder/Sites/tuts/source/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
         5: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/carrierwave-1.3.1/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:139:in `fog_credentials='
         4: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/carrierwave-1.3.1/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:126:in `eager_load_fog'
         3: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/fog-core-2.1.2/lib/fog/core/services_mixin.rb:16:in `new'
         2: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/fog-core-2.1.2/lib/fog/core/service.rb:98:in `new'
         1: from /Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/fog-core-2.1.2/lib/fog/core/service.rb:268:in `handle_settings'
/Users/homefolder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/fog-core-2.1.2/lib/fog/core/service.rb:244:in `validate_options': Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)
```

Please can anyone help to get this to work? Thanks for your help

Comment: Make sure `Rails.application.credentials.aws_key` and `Rails.application.credentials.aws_secret` are present.

Comment: @MarekLipka How would I check to see if they are present or not? (Sorry Im new to this)

Comment: Use `rails console` and check if these values are set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set credentials before using them.

Make sure you must have saved your credentials like following,

```
aws_key = # your key here
aws_secret = # secret here
```

For more information check [this](https://medium.com/cedarcode/rails-5-2-credentials-9b3324851336).

Comment: When I run EDITOR="atom --wait" rails credentials:edit - it pops up with credentials.yml file. In this file I have added the following -

Comment: development:
    aws_key: xxxxxxx
    aws_secret: xxxxxxxxx
    aws_bucket: xxxxxxxxx

  test:
    aws_key: xxxxxxx
    aws_secret: xxxxxxxxx
    aws_bucket: xxxxxxxxx

  production:
    aws_key: xxxxxxx
    aws_secret: xxxxxxxxx
    aws_bucket: xxxxxxxxx

Comment: However, this file name that pops up is called 49778.credentials.yml. In my credentials.yml, there just appears to be some encrypted line of code

Comment: Then you should access it with Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:aws_key].

Comment: Sorry, access it with which file?

Comment: replace Rails.application.credentials.aws_key with Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:aws_key] and others too.